# Create an Eleventy collection from SVG folder

Tags: svg, eleventy

**Hello everyone,**
I created a small SVG iconset and want to show them all rendered from a folder on one page using **Eleventy**. But at the same time, I would need the SVG code since users should be able to quickly copy the SVG code to the clipboard. There are some plugins for SVG content placement but I cannot use them in combination with an eleventy collection.

> I was able to place the SVG code into an eleventy page with [eleventy-plugin-svg-contents](https://github.com/brob/eleventy-plugin-svg-contents). But since the iconset will be 200+ icons I really do not want to copy & paste them all individually.

---

Additionally, I already managed to add all SVG files from a folder to a collection, but since it should be a vector icon set I cannot use image files.

```
{% for icon in collections.iconGallery %}
  <figure>
    <img class="m-2 w-6 h-6" src="{{ icon }}" alt="" />
  </figure>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**The following thing I would like to achieve:**

- Put all SVG icon-files in one folder
- Create a collection of all SVG files in that folder
- Show rendered SVG content (no `<img>` tag)
- Show name (filename without extension) and SVG code

**For testing purposes I will provide three icons as SVG code examples:**

```
<!-- annotation.svg -->
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M7 8H17M7 12H12M16.8284 17H19C20.1046 17 21 16.1046 21 15V6C21 4.89543 20.1046 4 19 4H5C3.89543 4 3 4.89543 3 6V15C3 16.1046 3.89543 17 5 17H7.17157C7.70201 17 8.21071 17.2107 8.58579 17.5858L10.5858 19.5858C11.3668 20.3668 12.6332 20.3668 13.4142 19.5858L15.4142 17.5858C15.7893 17.2107 16.298 17 16.8284 17Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></svg>

<!-- briefcase.svg -->
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M8 7H5C3.89543 7 3 7.89543 3 9V13M8 7V5C8 3.89543 8.89543 3 10 3H14C15.1046 3 16 3.89543 16 5V7M8 7H16M16 7H19C20.1046 7 21 7.89543 21 9V13M3 13V19C3 20.1046 3.89543 21 5 21H19C20.1046 21 21 20.1046 21 19V13M3 13H8M21 13H16M8 13H16M8 13V15M8 13V11M16 13V11M16 13V15" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></svg>

<!-- calendar.svg -->
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M4 9V19C4 20.1046 4.89543 21 6 21H18C19.1046 21 20 20.1046 20 19V9M4 9V7C4 5.89543 4.89543 5 6 5H8M4 9H20M20 9V7C20 5.89543 19.1046 5 18 5H16M16 5V3M16 5H8M8 3V5" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></svg>
```

I hope my question was clear enough and if you have any questions let me know in the comments.
Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you created the `iconGallery` collection? I think there are a couple of options to achieve your desired result. I would go with JavaScript data files instead of collections, but sounds like you're already halfway there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an alternate approach using [JavaScript data files](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-js/). Since you have full access to the file system through Node, you can just manually parse the folder into an array with all the information you need, including the SVG source.

Quick and dirty, might need some adjustments:

```js
// _data/icons.js
const fg = require('fast-glob');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const iconFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, '../path/to/your/icon/folder/');
        const svgIcons = await fg('**/*.svg', { cwd: iconFolder };
        const iconData = await Promise.all(svgIcons.map(async (name) => {
            const nameWithoutExtension = path.parse(name).name;
            const source = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(iconFolder, name), { encoding: 'utf8' });
            const sourceWithClass = source.replace('<svg', '<svg class="my-custom-class"');
            return { name, source, sourceWithClass, nameWithoutExtension };
        }));
        resolve(iconData);
    });
};
```

This data file returns an array of objects with the name (or path relative to the icon base folder, if there are subdirectories) and source of each SVG icon in the icon folder. Then you can iterate through that in your template and display the name and sources accordingly.

Note the example above uses [fast-glob](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob), though you can of course also manually iterate through the files in the folder using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

The same should be possible using collections, since you can put any data strcuture you want in a collection now.

### Accessing the data

Eleventy [automatically parses data file](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-global/) and makes them available to your templates. So you can access the icon data like this in any template (using Nunjucks syntax as an example):

```
{% for icon in icons %}
    <figure>
        {# output the svg source code including the added class. the safe filter is necessary to prevent nunjucks from escaping the SVG code  #}
        {{ icon.sourceWithClass | safe }}
        {# output the file name (excluding the extension) #}
        <figcaption>{{ icon.nameWithoutExtension }}</figcaption>
    </figure>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the variable name used to access the data (here: `icons`) depends on the name of the data file. See the [documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-global/) for details.

Comment: looks pretty good. How would I add those on an HTML page?

Comment: @GerritHalfmann I've updated the answer with an example of how to access the data in a template!

Comment: In my eleventy build I get this error:
`Unhandled rejection in promise ([object Promise]): (more in DEBUG output)
> Callback must be a function. Received { encoding: 'utf8' }`

Comment: @GerritHalfmann Ah sorry, I guess `readFile` requires a callback. Switch it to `fs.readFileSync` (without await, since this method is synchronous anyway) then it should work. I updated the example in my answer. Though I wrote this in the browser, so there might be some errors in there still. Make sure to check the code and understand how it works before copying it into your project, this will help your make any adjustments you might need to make for your specific use-case!

Comment: works great so far! I will mark it as solved because this is what I was asking initially. Although I would like to ask for two small updates:
- How can I add a class to all SVGs?
- The icon file name should be outputted without file extensions to use it for clipboardJS target attribute.
Thanks

Comment: @GerritHalfmann I've updated the code above with examples regarding your follow-up questions. But you can add any data you want in the object that's returned for each icon, so you can just use regular JavaScript string functions (ex: [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for adding a class) or NodeJS utility methods (ex: [path.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path) for getting the file name without extension) to modify the data  to the format you need.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much. I implemented all of this here: https://majesticons.com Thanks again!